# Combining multiple event functions jQuery

Tags: jquery

Forgive me not-so advanced approach but I'm looking for the best method to combine multiple functions into one.  Here's my code.  Basically, I have 6 steps one one page that request 6 different Ajax calls.  The problem is, oddly, they work when you start from the bottom of the page and work up, but starting from the top of the page going down, the event doesn't work.  any suggestions?  Thanks!

The html:

```
 <!--   Expanding Block 1     -->
<div class="row span10 center clearfix">  <a href="http://diyshedsupply.com/step-1-tab/"  class="show_hide btn btn-primary pull-right">+ -</a><div class="pull-right"> <strong> Specs and Details &nbsp; </strong></div><br />
</div>
<div class="row span10 center slidingDiv">

<div class="row span9 center clearfix">

<div id="ajax-content">Default Content</div>
</div>
</div>
<!--   Expanding Block      -->   

 <!--   Expanding Block  2     -->
<div class="row span10 center clearfix">  <a href="http://diyshedsupply.com/step-2-tab/"  class="show_hide2 btn btn-primary pull-right">+ -</a><div class="pull-right"> <strong> Specs and Details &nbsp; </strong></div><br />
</div>
<div class="row span10 center slidingDiv2">

<div class="row span9 center clearfix">

<div id="ajax-content2">Default Content</div>

</div>
</div>
<!--   Expanding Block      --> 

ect...
```

The JavaScript:

```
// Load Ajax Content Step 1 //


     $('.slidingDiv').hide();
     $('.show_hide').show();
     $('.show_hide').click(function () {
         $('.slidingDiv').slideToggle(1600, function () {
             $('.show_hide').addClass('close-tabs');
             /* do anything after animation is complete */
             $('ul.tabs').each(function (e) {
                 var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');
                 // If the location.hash matches one of the links, use that as the active tab.
                 // If no match is found, use the first link as the initial active tab.
                 $active = $($links.filter('[href="' + location.hash + '"]')[0] || $links[0]);
                 $active.addClass('active1');
                 $content = $($active.attr('href'));
                 // Hide the remaining content
                 $links.not($active).each(function () {
                     $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
                 });
                 // Bind the click event handler
                 $(this).on('click', 'a', function (e) {
                     // Make the old tab inactive.
                     $active.removeClass('active1');
                     $content.hide();
                     // Update the variables with the new link and content
                     $active = $(this);
                     $content = $($(this).attr('href'));
                     // Make the tab active.
                     $active.addClass('active1');
                     $content.show();
                     // Prevent the anchor's default click action
                     e.preventDefault();
                 });
             });
         });
         $('#ajax-content').empty().append("<div class='loading'><img src='/wp-content/themes/diy/img/ajax-loader.gif' alt='Loading' /></div>");
         $('.show_hide a').removeClass('current');
         $(this).addClass('current');
         $.ajax({
             url: this.href,
             success: function (html) {
                 $("#ajax-content").empty().append(html);
             }
         });
         return false;
     });


// Load Ajax Content Step 2 //

     $('.slidingDiv2').hide();
     $('.show_hide2').show();
     $('.show_hide2').click(function () {
         $('.slidingDiv2').slideToggle(1600, function () {
             $('.show_hide2').addClass('close-tabs');
             /* do anything after animation is complete */
             $('ul.tabs2').each(function (e) {
                 var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');
                 // If the location.hash matches one of the links, use that as the active tab.
                 // If no match is found, use the first link as the initial active tab.
                 $active = $($links.filter('[href="' + location.hash + '"]')[0] || $links[0]);
                 $active.addClass('active2');
                 $content = $($active.attr('href'));
                 // Hide the remaining content
                 $links.not($active).each(function () {
                     $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
                 });
                 // Bind the click event handler
                 $(this).on('click', 'a', function (e) {
                     // Make the old tab inactive.
                     $active.removeClass('active2');
                     $content.hide();
                     // Update the variables with the new link and content
                     $active = $(this);
                     $content = $($(this).attr('href'));
                     // Make the tab active.
                     $active.addClass('active2');
                     $content.show();
                     // Prevent the anchor's default click action
                     e.preventDefault();
                 });
             });
         });
         $('#ajax-content2').empty().append("<div class='loading'><img src='/wp-content/themes/diy/img/ajax-loader.gif' alt='Loading' /></div>");
         $('.show_hide2 a').removeClass('current');
         $(this).addClass('current');
         $.ajax({
             url: this.href,
             success: function (html) {
                 $("#ajax-content2").empty().append(html);
             }
         });
         return false;
     });
```

Comment: too long, didn't read...

Comment: still far too long.  Please reduce your code to the _bare minimum_ required to actually describe your problem.

Comment: So, If you click on the 6th link then 5th link, etc it works but if you click them in order (1,2,3) the content tabs don't work.  If you click them like this (6, 4, 5) 6 and 4 work, but 5 doesn't get tabs.

Comment: Correct.  It doesn't work in this order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot about jquery's [`index()` function](http://jquery.com/index/).

You can try something like this:

HTML

```
<div class="row span10 center clearfix">
    <a href="http://diyshedsupply.com/step-1-tab/"  class="show_hide btn btn-primary pull-right">+ -</a>
    <div class="pull-right"><strong> Specs and Details</strong></div><br />
</div>
<div class="row span10 center slidingDiv"> 
    <div class="row span9 center clearfix">
        <div id="ajax-content0" data-fetched="false">Default Content</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row span10 center clearfix">
    <a href="http://diyshedsupply.com/step-1-tab/"  class="show_hide btn btn-primary pull-right">+ -</a>
    <div class="pull-right"><strong> Specs and Details</strong></div><br />
</div>
<div class="row span10 center slidingDiv"> 
    <div class="row span9 center clearfix">
        <div id="ajax-content1" data-fetched="false">Default Content</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row span10 center clearfix">
    <a href="http://diyshedsupply.com/step-1-tab/"  class="show_hide btn btn-primary pull-right">+ -</a>
    <div class="pull-right"><strong> Specs and Details</strong></div><br />
</div>
<div class="row span10 center slidingDiv"> 
    <div class="row span9 center clearfix">
        <div id="ajax-content2" data-fetched="false">Default Content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.show_hide').click(function (e) {
    var index = $('.show_hide').index(this); //which one am I working with?
    //check if content has already been loaded via ajax
    if($("#ajax-content" + index).attr('data-fetched') === 'false') {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.href,
            beforeSend: function () {
                $('#ajax-content' + index).html("<div class='loading'><img src='/wp-content/themes/diy/img/ajax-loader.gif' alt='Loading' /></div>");
            },
            success: function (html) {
                $("#ajax-content" + index).html(html);
                $("#ajax-content" + index).attr('data-fetched', 'true');
                $('.show_hide:eq(' + index + ')').addClass('close-tabs');
                handletabs(index);
                $('.slidingDiv:eq(' + index + ')').slideToggle(1600, function () {
                    /* do anything after animation is complete */
                });
                $('.show_hide:eq(' + index + ')' + ' a').removeClass('current');
                $(this).addClass('current');
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('.slidingDiv:eq(' + index + ')').slideToggle(1600);
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});

function handletabs(index) {
    $('.slidingDiv:eq(' + index + ')' + ' ul.tabs').each(function (e) {
        //foreach new tab
        //bind to click event
        $(this).on('click', function (e) {
            //remove active class from all links in parent('tabby')
            $(e).parents('tabby').children('a').removeClass('active');
            //add to new link
            $(e).addClass('active');
            //hide all divs in parent('tabby')
            $(e).parents('tabby').children('div').hide();
            //use href to show div
            $($(this).attr('href')).show();
            // Prevent the anchor's default click action
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: The div won't expand at all with that vortextangent.

Comment: Sorry, there were a few edits I had to do. It probably wasn't doing the ajax call.

Comment: @DennySmith make sure to start from 0 with your `forloop` or use `<?php echo '#ajax-content' . $index-1 ?>` (i'm seeing your live edits...)

Comment: Also, I might move `handletabs` outside of the `slideToggle` callback so it happens before the slide completes.

Comment: Yeah, I just changed that back to 0.  Thanks a bunch man.  That definitely shortened the code immensity.  Now, if I could just get those dang jQuey tabs to work like they should.  Plus, I found a little syntax error but it was a quick fix.  You had             handletabs(index); }} I added handletabs(index); }) }

Comment: I found it.  In my Ajax pages, I had assigned unique classes to the tabs.  I made them all the same and it works like a charm!  Cheers!

Comment: Foiled!  Would you have any logical explanation why my tabs work when you scroll to the bottom then sequentially open them from reverse order.  If you open and close my divs starting from 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 they work.  If you start from 1 and go to 2 they don't. Weird!

Comment: ya, the ids need to be unique, use something like 'step-1-tab1'.  also, make sure to edit the href in links to match

Comment: Got it!  Sometimes it's the most obvious things I overlook.  Thanks again mate!

Answer (score 0):

First, from what I see, the first problem is the redundancy of informations. You need some sort of unique function to use with your different parameters, maybe a generic function passed to the event via binding could be an answer.

Second, since the steps are pretty the same, why not consider to use some array to iterate containing only the reference to ID, classes, etc? In this way you reduce all to some simple `for` loop on some array which passes parameters to binded callbacks.

**EDIT:**

You can use the `event.data` [optional object](http://api.jquery.com/event.data/) for the events (since you're using jQuery). This is just an idea that you have to improve, of course:

```
var NUM_OF_SECTIONS = 6;

function mySlidingFunc( event ) {
  $('.slidingDiv' + event.data.id).slideToggle( 1600, function () {
     $('.show_hide' + event.data.id).addClass('close-tabs');
     /* do anything after animation is complete */

     // here the rest of the code ....
  });
}

for ( var i = 0 ; i < NUM_OF_SECTIONS; i++ ) {
  $('.slidingDiv' + i).hide();
  $('.show_hide' + i).show();
  $('.show_hide').on('click', { id: i }, mySlidingFunc );
}
```

That's all. 1 loop and 1 function for 6 or more iterations over your elements into the HTML.

Comment: Here is the page I'm working on. http://diyshedsupply.com/  You can see the idea behind what I'm attempting.  I'm sort of a noob at arrays, could you explain a little please?  Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I really appreciate it.  How would I target data-index='0' in my jQuery then?

Comment: I've added a little example of what you can do with jQuery.